# How to make Slider similar/gallery to the Amazon product Slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I building a website, and I am not good in js or jQuery. I have no idea what to do. I was in search for couple days, to find any library that support this feature. However, there are different libraries I found, but most of them are separate from what I need, zoom and thumbnails. It has to be similar to Amazon or eBay product listing slider.

Can any one give me a clue where should I start?

PS. I tried swiper.js, but it has zoom only on double click.

**Updated 5/16/2017**

Example

[image]

Comment: Seems like any major slider would do that if you configure it to be like ebay/amazon. Have you looked at flexslider?

Comment: @MichaelCoker yes, but would not help because I dont have good experience in the js

Comment: Which slider you referring in amazon main slider or products slider?

Comment: @RajKumarBhardwaj product slider

Comment: http://prntscr.com/f8bsfn   this one?  can you show me your website link?

Comment: @RajKumarBhardwaj no, not this one. Probably. I was wrong. The main one that has thumbnail and zoom. When you going to the product. You will see slider on the left side.

Answer (score 1):

Hi first of all visit to the link http://www.landmarkmlp.com/js-plugin/owl.carousel/ and download slider.

open your header of the website theme and put the js and CSS which one mentions into the snippet below, and replace the images, js and css files path which where it is.

After that put the HTML sections where you would like to show your slider, and replace the div with your dynamic products loop code.

```js
 $(document).ready(function($) {
      $("#owl-example").owlCarousel();
    });


    $("body").data("page", "frontpage");
```

```html
<link href="http://www.landmarkmlp.com/js-plugin/owl.carousel/assets/css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Owl Carousel Assets -->
    <link href="http://www.landmarkmlp.com/js-plugin/owl.carousel/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="http://www.landmarkmlp.com/js-plugin/owl.carousel/owl-carousel/owl.theme.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <div id="demo">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="span12">

              <div id="owl-example" class="owl-carousel">

                <div class="item darkCyan">
                  <img src="http://www.landmarkmlp.com/js-plugin/owl.carousel/assets/img/demo-slides/touch.png" alt="Touch">
                    <h3>Touch</h3>
                    <h4>Can touch this</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="item forestGreen">
                  <img src="http://www.landmarkmlp.com/js-plugin/owl.carousel/assets/img/demo-slides/grab.png" alt="Grab">
                    <h3>Grab</h3>
                    <h4>Can grab this</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="item orange">
                  <img src="http://www.landmarkmlp.com/js-plugin/owl.carousel/assets/img/demo-slides/responsive.png" alt="Responsive">
                    <h3>Responsive</h3>
                    <h4>Fully responsive!</h4>
                </div>

                <div class="item yellow">
                  <img src="http://www.landmarkmlp.com/js-plugin/owl.carousel/assets/img/demo-slides/css3.png" alt="CSS3">
                    <h3>CSS3</h3>
                    <h4>3D Acceleration.</h4>
                </div>

                <div class="item dodgerBlue">
                  <img src="http://www.landmarkmlp.com/js-plugin/owl.carousel/assets/img/demo-slides/multi.png" alt="Multi">
                    <h3>Multiply</h3>
                    <h4>Owls on page.</h4>
                </div>

                <div class="item skyBlue">
                  <img src="http://www.landmarkmlp.com/js-plugin/owl.carousel/assets/img/demo-slides/modern.png" alt="Modern Browsers">
                    <h3>Modern</h3>
                    <h4>Browsers Compatibility</h4>
                </div>

                <div class="item zombieGreen">
                  <img src="http://www.landmarkmlp.com/js-plugin/owl.carousel/assets/img/demo-slides/zombie.png" alt="Zombie Browsers - old ones">
                    <h3>Zombie</h3>
                    <h4>Browsers Compatibility</h4>
                </div>

                <div class="item violet">
                  <img src="http://www.landmarkmlp.com/js-plugin/owl.carousel/assets/img/demo-slides/controls.png" alt="Take Control">
                    <h3>Take Control</h3>
                    <h4>The way you like</h4>
                </div>

                <div class="item yellowLight">
                  <img src="http://www.landmarkmlp.com/js-plugin/owl.carousel/assets/img/demo-slides/feather.png" alt="Light">
                    <h3>Light</h3>
                    <h4>As a feather</h4>
                </div>

                <div class="item steelGray">
                  <img src="http://www.landmarkmlp.com/js-plugin/owl.carousel/assets/img/demo-slides/tons.png" alt="Tons of Opotions">
                    <h3>Tons</h3>
                    <h4>of options</h4>
                </div>

              </div>


            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://www.landmarkmlp.com/js-plugin/owl.carousel/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
```

Hope so it will work for you. You just need to update files path according where it is situated in your website files directories.

Comment: This not what I meant, I was saying the slider that has gallery in it.